# Separating dictionary into smaller dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary and want to divide it into smaller dictionaries, for example for:

```
dic = {1:(2,6), 3:(4,5)}
```

I want to loop it and have a "current" dictionary `current = {1:2, 3:4}` for first iteration, and current `{1:6, 3:5}` for the second iteration. Here's what I've tried (and doesn't work):

```
dic = {1:(2,6), 3:(4,5)}

for i in range (0,1):
    for key in dic:
        current = {}
        current[key] = dic[key][i]
    print (current)
```

this outputs `{3:4}` and `{3:5}`, it skips the key "1" for some reason. How do i fix this?

Also, how do I find the number of the values of the keys assuming every key has equal number of values? e.g. for `{2:[3,4,5,7], 3:[1,0,3,1]}` that would be 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are overwriting `current` on each iteration, define it before iterating, and `range(0, 1)` loops through [0] only:

```
dic = {1:(2,6), 3:(4,5)}

for i in range(2):
    current = {}
    for key in dic:
        current[key] = dic[key][i]
    print(current)
```

Comment: Don't worry @user3037568 now you know your mistake you can make sure you don't do it again :)

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you could create the new dictionaries, iterate through the keys of the original dict and create the dictionaries accordingly:

```
dic = {1:(2,6), 3:(4,5)}
d1, d2 = {}, {}
for key, v in dic.items():
    d1[key], d2[key] = v 
print(d1, d2)
```

Which prints out:

```
{1: 2, 3: 4} {1: 6, 3: 5}
```

`d1[key], d2[key] = v` simply unpacks the value for `v` in `d1[key]` and `d2[key]` accordingly.